# Add a repository for security testing

Tags: apt, security, repository

I want to use some security tools because I study security (A total beginner). I tried adding the repos of kali, and install some security tools from there, the security tools works great but I had some problem later with installing some packages from the official Ubuntu repository (like wine), problems like `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

So is there a repository especially created for Ubuntu for security pen-testers and that won't cause any problems with the official Ubuntu packages ??

I know that some of you will tell me to go to kali, but I just can't, I am too attached to Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post the commands you used to add the kali repos?

Comment: Please don't mix Kali repositories with Ubuntu, if you already did and perform charges I recommend you to backup and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mitch I didn't use command, I added the kali repository in the source.list file and put then in comments ; then, every time I need to install a tool from kali,  I remove the comments and install the tool, then I comment the repository again when I finish.

Comment: @xangua What are the alternatives to get security testing tools ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great tool to install pentest tools on Ubuntu. It's name is Pentesters Framework (ptf).

You can install It from this [link](https://github.com/trustedsec/ptf) , and see this link for a  [description](https://www.trustedsec.com/may-2015/new-tool-the-pentesters-framework-ptf-released/).